# how to set a length of a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sqldatasource

i have the store procedure and i have passed the value as output which will return the value as string but the string is showing only length of 1 but on store procedure i have set the length(max) but the output is still single 
 eg the output should be mr-01-1 but only showing m

the store procedure is called as

```
SqlParameter[] param1 = new SqlParameter[1];

var a = string.Empty;
List<Object> objParamDetails = new List<Object>();

SqlParameter MemberId = new SqlParameter("@MemberId", a);
MemberId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
param1[0] = MemberId;
```

Comment: Can you add the stored procedure code?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `VarChar` instead of `string`

```
SqlParameter MemberId = new SqlParameter("@MemberId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
MemberId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

There's an [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z(v=vs.110).aspx) for setting up the param with additional properties.

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@MemberId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
parameter.Size = integer value;
parameter.Value = "";
```

or, just use

```
SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@MemberId", 
        SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "");
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```